# Unable to loop for different data

Tags: java

I am unable to loop through my database for timeList to output different time that I require. They only loop through the first one and display the same data for every output that I require. If I were to close the for loop of of the conversion, I would have problem displaying it in the output statement.

```
String[] timeMinute = timeList .split("<SPLIT>");

            for (int t = 0; t <timeMinute.length; t ++)
            {
                String strDate = timeList;
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
                Date getDate = sdf.parse(strDate);
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTime(getDate);
                int noOfHours = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int noOfMinutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                int totalMinutes = noOfHours * 60 + noOfMinutes;

            while ( rs.next() )
            {   
                String RTD= rs.getString("RTD");
                if ( !trd1.contains( RTD) )
                    trd1.add(RTD);

                String admissionCOUNT = "";

                if ( rs.getString("jae") != null )
                    admission  = rs.getString("jae");

                String[] admissionCOUNT = admission.split("<SPLIT>");

                for ( int i = 0 ; i <gateNo.length ; i ++ )
                {
                    if ( kpm.containsKey(gateNo[i]) )
                        kpm.get(admissionCOUNT [i]).put(RTD, + totalMinutes);
                }
            }

            for ( int i = 0 ; i < .size(); i++)
            {
                stringWriter.append( trd1.get(i)  + ",");

                for ( String admissionCOUNT : kpm.keySet() )
                {
                    if ( kpm.get(admissionCOUNT ).containsKey(trd1.get(i)  ) )
                        MSO.get(admissionCOUNT ).append(totalMinutes +",");
                    else
                        MSO.get(admissionCOUNT ).append("0,");
                }

            }
```

The current output example -

```
data1,0,56,0

data2,56,0,0

data3,56,0,0

data4,0,0,56
```

Desire output example -

```
data1,0,87,0

data2,56,0,0

data3,43,0,0

data4,0,0,91
```

edit:

```
for ( String egm : .keySet() )
                resultString += System.getProperty("line.separator") + gate + "," + MSO.get(egm).toString();
```

Comment: you should be using `timeMinute [i]` somewhere in your code for you to achieve this, what does your `timeMinute[]` contain(format of things)?

Comment: @Vihar it contains the data from the database. Suggestion on where do i include it?

Comment: It is little difficult to read your code, where are you fetching data for last 3 fields?

Comment: @NamanGala All the data are from database which i didn't include the query. I only added those necessary lines that might help.

Comment: What are these variables `MSO`, `kpm`, `trd1`? And show us your printing part which is printing `data1,0,56,0`

Comment: @NamanGala those are the variables which the data are stored in. I'll edit the codes now.